# Delphi.NET Socket BeginSend callback never get called

Tags: delphi.net

Recently, i found my application, which's developped under Delphi.NET, the socket callback function never get called, causing the socket message cannot be sent to the target client.

Is it possible a bug of the socket class in Delphi.NET? Or will it be relative to the Anti Virus software, or something else? Since this problem only happen in some workstation, but not all my testing environment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i've got the answer, it's just because .NET Framework 1.1 hasn't been installed in the workstation, once installed, all goes fine

Answer (score 0):

You're highly likely sending it to the wrong endpoint. Make sure your socket is connected before sending messages.

Until we see some code we're unable to help you any further.

Comment: thanks for you post, i should make it more clear that the socket at first is working fine, but under my stress test, i found some data's missing, and per my deep checking, i finally found it's that there's no function callback, seems that some data hasn't reached the target host